# To publish json data in dropdown Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my json data

```
  {
  "JohnDoe":{
     "fullName":{
        "en":"Mr John Doe"
     },
     "description":{
        "en":"Lorem Ipsum."
     },
     "identifier":"com.john.doe"
  },
  "JaneDoe":{
     "fullName":{
        "en":"Ms Jane Doe"
     },
     "description":{
        "en":"Lorem Ipsum."
     },
     "identifier":"com.jane.doe"
  }
}
```

I want to display name as text and identifier as value in dropdown.

Here is the code i tried in blade file:

```
<select name="name">
    @foreach ($data as $key => $node)
        @foreach ($node as $index => $value)

          {!! dd($value) !!}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
   </select>
```

This is my controller

```
return view('people.index', ['data' => json_decode($data, true)]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have access to the elements of each node with the first `foreach` loop you created, so you can do something like this:

```
<select name="name">
    @foreach ($data as $key => $node)
        @foreach ($node['fullName'] as $code => $name)
            <option value="{{ $node['identifier'] }}">{{ $name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: yes i can do that but what if there is more than en